# Change font & background color in ipython notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

How to change the C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\html\notebook\static\css
file in the iPython notebook directory without destroying the source file?

I just want to have a black background in the notebook, and then have orange text colors with blue or whatever for classes and functions.

Can anyone help in this one? I know where to find the source files but not how to modify them.

I appreciate any answers. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a file named `custom.css` in `<ipython profile dir>/profile_<profilename>/static/custom/custom.css` that will be applied to your notebook.  Browser caching might be aggressive, you might need to force refresh a few times.

Coloring of words is done through [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/demo/theme.html), which supports theming.  Changing this will be slightly more involved and might require some JavaScript injection in `<ipython profile dir>/profile_<profilename>/static/custom/custom.js`.

I wrote a more detailed, but outdated, [explanation](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/Carreau/posts/master/02-css-selector.ipynb) which can probably be adapted to new versions.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how can it be done with codemirror? Or post a link with an explanation. Thanks

Comment: in js : Loop through cells of `IPython.notebook.get_cells()`. `cell.code_mirror.setOption('theme','monokai')`. and `IPython.Cell.defualt_options.cm_options.theme = 'monokai'` (so new cell get created with new theme) Might need to load monokai css theme also. haven't done it in recent version and pretty busy right now.

Comment: Also, be aware that this solution only works with ipython-notebook >= 1.0.0