# how to increase number of characters per line in version 1.1.0?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

IPython version 0.13.0 display more characters per line in Notebook by default than version 1.1.0. Can I increase the number of characters displayed in 1.1.0? The default leaves a lot fo the screen unused.

Comment: More precisely, 0.13.2 by default did not have margins at the left and the right of the screen when displaying a notebook and, as a result, used the whole screen. It looks like 1.1.0 has some margins by default. How can I get rid of those margins and go back to 0.13.2 default behavior? Can it be done through custom.css?

Comment: You can change the CSS as you like. See: [Change font & background color in ipython notebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706701/change-font-background-color-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: Could you give me a code snippet? I don't really know CSS and I am happy with the way IPython displays notebooks by default, except that I want to get rid of the margins.

Comment: You have a bunch of snippets in the notebook that is linked in the answer of the question I pointed to: [notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/Carreau/posts/master/02-css-selector.ipynb)

Comment: Can someone else help me here? I am comparing ipython.min.css in 1.1.0 with notebook.css in 0.13.2 and cannot figure out what drives the difference in behavior. I see much more extensive use of -webkit-box things in 1.1.0, but I have no idea what that is. Is that what drives the difference in behavior? If so, how can I get rid of those annoying margins?