# ipython: change text and background color

Tags: ipython

How can I change the text and background color of the help dialog in ipython?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706701/change-font-background-color-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: @ti7 - I could not find what exactly needs to be changed, to change the colors. Could you please make your comment an answer, and include the specific code?